Fix copper drain pipe hole
I have a leak coming from a hole on a copper drain pipe.
I was wondering if I'd need to get a coupling soldered over it or of I could get away with cutting the pipe and sliding a rubber connector over the hole.
Thank you for your time.

Either of those choices will work.  A better question might be why it is spitting.  It looks like it has been soldered before.  Any chance this pipe can freeze?  Drain pipes usually have no freezing problems, but that is what you find after a pipe freezes and bursts.

Kinda does look like it might've been brazed, but it's hard to tell.  Personally, if there's sufficient access, I'd cut out as much of the pipe with the greenish tinge as I could and sweat in a new section of pipe.  But given that this is only a drain pipe, clamping rubber over it may suffice.
